# CLIENT PROGRAM ERROR An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, eclipse, client

I use a client program in my local machine to connect to a server. communication is excellent till the network goes down. Once the network goes offline I am trying to close the socket and reconnect. But, shutdown() and close() are not working as expected in Client program. so far I have seen shutdown() and close() in server program and not in any client program. please help me if there is any way to solve the issue.

```
    import socket,time
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    ip = '192.168.10.3'
    port = 4196
    address = (ip,port)

    def con():
        client.connect(address)
        print("connected")

    def comm():
        while 1:
            try:
                client.send(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x71\xcb')
                print("sent")
                data= client.recv(1024)
                print(" ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in (data)))
                time.sleep(10)
            except ConnectionResetError:
                print("reset error")
                client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
                client.close()
                time.sleep(20)
                con()


    con()
    comm() 


    Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 17, in comm
        datasent = client.send(b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x71\xcb')
        ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 30, in <module>
           comm()
        File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 26, in comm
           con()
        File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 11, in con
           client.connect(address)
           OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: You have to create a new socket to reconnect. And try not to do recursive calls.

Comment: can I use the same IP and port to create a new socket?

Comment: @KlausD. Creating a new socket means, closing the existing one and trying to connect it back. correct?

Comment: No, restarting the car doesn't make it a new car. You have to rerun `socket.socket(...)`.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried to call the socket.socket() but couldn't do it proper. I am new to programming. Please let me know if the client = socket.socket() needs to be called or I need to include any piece of code in the exception? any examples will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: not required, It worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for resolving @KlausD. have to create a new socket to reconnect. to rerun socket.socket(...),